# Why Quine–McCluskey algorithm is considered as an analogous to Buchberger's algorithm?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, logic, soft-question, algorithms, boolean-algebra

According to the wikipedia pages of

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm

These two algorithms are analogous to each other but Wikipedia does not provide further explanation or any comparison criterias.

My question is why Quine–McCluskey algorithm is considered as an analogous to Buchberger's algorithm ?

[image]

If this is true then there is an interesting consequences

Notice that there is a step in the Quine–McCluskey algorithm that required us to solve and NP-hard problem called "[The set covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)" problem.  I am also wondering that what would be the equivalence NP-hard problem that the Buchberger's algorithm required us to solve under the assumption that Quine–McCluskey algorithm and Buchberger's algorithm is analogous ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm

Comment: Boolean expressions can be considered polynomials. I think that is the analogy.

Comment: Did you find anything more precise on this? For example a proof that, when considering boolean expressions as polynomials, the Buchberger algorithm applied to such a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ reduces to the Quine-McCluskey algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean calculating the groebner bases over GF(2). This is something that people in the channel coding community has already done before.